# How to reverse an array and store the values of the reversed array in a new array

Tags: c, arrays, reverse, function-definition

My program needs to do the following:

1. Reverse a array(f.e. `niz[] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3 }` needs to become `niz[] = { 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 4, 2 }`
2. Store the values of a reversed array into a brand new array
3. All of it has to be done without using `printf` inside the function that reverses the array and stores the values into the new array. Also, the array and its size need to be predefined (so no user input).
4. The result (in this case the new array that contains the reversed values of the previous array) needs to be printed in `main`

However, instead of reversing the array and storing it into a new array and returning it. The program always prints the following numbers:

```
6356668
```

So does anyone see the problem in my code?

```c
int koko(int *array, int *array2, int c, int d) {
    for (c = 6; c > -1; c--, d++) {
        array2[d] = array[c];
    }
    return array2;
}

int main() {
    int niz[] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3 };
    int niz2[7];
    int a, b, c;
    c = koko(niz, niz2, a, b);
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

Comment: You are passing in (and using) b which is not assigned a value.

Comment: And whilst not the cause of the problem you are also needlessly passing in `a` and never actually using the value passed in (though `a` is uninitialised anyway).

Comment: Besides the fact that you are passing in unassigned variables. In your `koko` function, why not just declare `int c` and `int d` inside the function? This will cut down on the number of arguments passed in and makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use new array as the argument of `koko` function, so you do not need to return it. If you want to return it, you should change the type of returning from `int` to `int *`.

In `koko` function, `d` has to always begin at `0`, so you do not need to declare it as the argument of this function. Let's declare it as the local variable in this function.

`c` is one of iterator of `for` loop, so let's declare it in this function with the initial value equals to `size - 1` (`size` is the size of array or the number of elements in this array).

BTW, this function become as below:

```
void koko(int *array,int *array2,int size)
{
    int d = 0;
    int c;
    for(c = size - 1;c>-1;c--,d++)
    {
        array2[d]=array[c];
    }
}
```

For using this function in main, you just need to give two arrays and size of the array (`7` in this case):

```
 koko(niz,niz2,7);
```

The complete code for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void koko(int *array,int *array2,int size)
{
    int d = 0;
    int c;
    for(c = size - 1;c>-1;c--,d++)
    {
        array2[d]=array[c];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int niz[]={2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3};
    int niz2[7];
    koko(niz,niz2,7);
    for(int i = 0; i <7; i++)
        printf("%d ",niz2[i]);
}
```

The output:

```
3 8 4 7 5 4 2
```

Comment: Why i have 2 down votes ?  Would the downvoters care to explain ?

Comment: My bet goes to some issues with the quality of the code, size should not be an int literal, it should at the minimum be a constant since it is used in several instances, c is totally unnecessary, the condition  c > -1 is not up to par, check out the other answers and see the difference, that said I also got 1 downvote, so it mignt be someone who just felt like downoting all the answers, who knows. It's a feature of the site, one might aswell get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

> So does anyone see the problem in my code?

Yes:

- `d` receives an unitialized parameter `c`, since you never initialize it in the scope of the function before using it, it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).
- The return type of `koko` is incorrect given that you are trying to return `array2`, effectively `niz2`, you would need `int*` return type, not `int`.

  Moreover you wouldn't need to do this because an array passed as argument of a function decays to a pointer to it's first element, even if the parameter is not explicitly a pointer, the changes made to it in the scope of the function are permanent.

Based on your code, you can do something like:

[Running sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2zLoJUbvoNAGDxlK)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void koko(int *array, int *array2, size_t size) // pass the size of the array
{                                              // size_t more appropriate for object sizes  
    for (int j = 0; size > 0; size--, j++) // initialize j, you can use size as iterator
    {
        array2[j] = array[size - 1]; // changes made to array2 are permanent
    }
}

int main()
{
    int niz[] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3};
    const size_t SIZE = sizeof(niz) / sizeof(niz[0]); // determine the size of the array
    int niz2[SIZE]; // same size as non reversed array

    koko(niz, niz2, SIZE);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) // test print the reversed array
        printf("%d", niz2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit... How about `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)` -> `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes, thanks, I guess I dodged a bullet there.

Comment: Well we all make mistakes don't we?  I probably deserved a downvote for so many silly bugs in my answer, due to a late change of variable names and ill advised copy/paste... It is a long and tough road to simplicity, but worth the trip :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass 4 arguments to `koko`, just the arrays and the number of elements is enough. Also do not compare to `-1`, write the loop as a down loop that stops at `0`, this way you can use unsigned index types, such as `size_t`. Even better use a classic loop with an index going from 0 to `length` excluded and store the source element to the appropriate destination element.

The reason you get a single meaningless number as output is you printf the return value of `koko`, which is mistyped as `int` whereas you return a pointer to the destination array, and you cannot print an array this way anyway, you muse use a loop to iterate over the array elements.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void koko(const int *array, int *array2, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array2[length - 1 - i] = array[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    int niz[] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3 };
    size_t length = sizeof(niz) / sizeof(niz[0]);
    int niz2[length];
    koko(niz, niz2, length);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", niz2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The return type of the function is incorrect.

```
int koko(int *array,int *array2,int c,int d)
{
for(c=6;c>-1;c--,d++)
{
    array2[d]=array[c];
}
return array2;
}
```

The returned expression has the type `int *` while the return type is `int`.

And this call

```
c=koko(niz,niz2,a,b);
```

does not make sense because the variables `a` and `b` are uninitialized.

Also this single call of the function `printf`

```
printf("%d", c);
```

has nothing common with outputting the whole result array.

It seems what you need is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * reverse( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    int *result = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            result[i] = a[n - i - 1];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int *b = reverse( a, N );

    if ( b != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", b[i] );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( b );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 8 4 7 5 4 2
```

If you want to copy an array in another already existent array in the reverse order then the corresponding function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_copy( const int *a, size_t n, int *b )
{
    const int *p = a + n;

    while ( p-- != a )
    {
        *b++ = *p;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 7 };
    int a[N] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3 };
    int b[N];

    reverse_copy( a, N, b );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", b[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above.

```
3 8 4 7 5 4 2
```

Without introducing any additional variable (that is in fact redundant) in the function it can be defined this way

```
void reverse_copy( const int *a, size_t n, int *b )
{
    while ( n-- )
    {
        *b++ = a[n];
    }
}
```

As you can see inside the function there are used only its parameters.

By the way a recursive function can look the following way.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_copy( const int *a, size_t n, int *b )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        *b = a[n-1];
        reverse_copy( a, n - 1, b + 1 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 7 };
    int a[N] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 8, 3 };
    int b[N];

    reverse_copy( a, N, b );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", b[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Again its output is

```
3 8 4 7 5 4 2
```